# Spring Xd for log management

Tags: spring-xd

I would like to use spring xd to ingest some log files and indexing those files into Apache solr for subsequent searches.
In order to use the "file" source, the directory has to be local to machine where spring xd is running. 
Is it the proper way to use spring xd as agent running on all the application servers in order to collect log data and send those logs to a centralized server for indexing purpose? 
It makes sense?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are cases where it could make sense to have XD container JVM (where the XD file source module would be deployed) running on the application server host. In this case, you might as well combine the data processing logic (a processor module that does the filtering of data) with the "composed module" to benefit from data affinity and reduce the amount of data over network. But if there are any constraints, you could use SFTP source module that helps you transfer files from remote hosts to a single host where spring XD container is running.

Comment: If you install the XD Container VM on the machine where the log files are written, you could also take advantage of the Spring XD tail source. This way you don't need to wait until a logfile has finished writing, but you get the newest log messages while the log file is being written.